# Angularfire - Property 'setCustomUserClaims' does not exist on type 'User'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I am using Angular 17, and AngularFire 17. I want to set up custom claims so that I can use roles in auth, but for some reason, the User object does not seem to have the setCustomUserClaims() function. The User object also does not seem to be present in the "compat" version. I am very new to Firebase/AngularFire and could use some help to understand what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

```
import { inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, authState, User, user } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { FirebaseService } from './firebase.service';
import { Role } from '../interfaces/role';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private auth: Auth = inject(Auth);
  user$ = user(this.auth);
  authState$ = authState(this.auth);
  userSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private firebaseService: FirebaseService) {
    this.userSubscription = this.user$.subscribe((aUser: User | null) => {
      //handle user state changes here. Note, that user will be null if there is no currently logged in user.
      if (aUser) {
        //user is logged in
        // set the admin role on the user
        aUser.setCustomUserClaims({ admin: true }).then(() => { }); // THIS LINE IS THE ERROR
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible for a user to set their own custom claims in the frontend of an app.  That's a massive security hole.  Custom claims should only be set using fully secured backend code.  Otherwise, people could simply grant themselves access to whatever claims they want.

In fact, this function `setCustomUserClaims` is only available in the Firebase Admin SDK, which is exclusively for backend use.  You're probably copying from the [example code in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk).  That code only works with Firebase Admin running on nodejs, and not any of the client SDKs.

If you need to set a custom claim for a user, you can write a standalone nodejs program using firebase-admin to get started quickly.  Or you can integrate this into your backend, and provide the frontend some way to invoke it for a user, if that's what you need.